# Share privately a Voila/JupyterLab result

Tags: jupyter-lab, voila

I can see locally my jupyter notebook using Voila, but now I need to share that to someone (privately so not deploy it). How can I let this person visualize my Voila app without having anything installed on its computer, using a container for example?

Or, is it an option to deploy it and keep it private using a key/password to access.

Comment: Deploying is possible, see [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/216) and [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/239). There was also [mention of SaturnCloud.io](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/265#issuecomment-508307318). I don't know what the sharing model there is.

Comment: Plus, if you can share a JupyterHub access with the user, you can use [this](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/new-dashboard-publishing-extension-for-jupyterhub/4202 ) to share Voila dashboards with authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to deploy Voila using heroku.

Comment: @Wayne What about multiple Dashboards in a single App, proper menu to opt which dashboard to view now? And also user login features? Which set of tool stack do I need to learn? Preferably all based on Python.

Comment: You can do [tabs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#Tabs) with ipwidgets. (I thought one of the galleries had an example?) That would allow you to switch dashboard views. Or use a drop-down. For logging in, see [this discussion](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/216). There are several other app/dashboard systems now in the ecosystem, see [Holoviz Panel](https://twitter.com/JupyterTutorial/status/1584440212113231872), Plotly Dash, or MavenWorks. Traditionally you'd do something like this with Flask or Django in combination with HTML & CSS.